# Redirect to page which exist as a string property in controller

Tags: javascript, redirect, jsf-2, primefaces

I create the content of an xhtml page in the business layer and I pass it as a string to the JSF controller through a service. I am using Primefaces as a view technology.

How can I display the page in the browser, since the page content is saved in a String property of the controller?

The page I am generating in the BL it's supposed to be a statical page. It has nothing to do with the Web page I use to retrieve that file. It's a html page you could open statically with a browser.

Is there an easier way than write the string content to an xhtml file on the filesystem and then redirect to the created xhtml file?

The controller looks like this:

```
public class PageController{

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    private String doc;

    public createDoc(){
         doc = service.createDoc();
    }
}
```

how can I retrieve the doc content as an xhtml page to the browser? The doc content looks like:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head> ..... 
    ...............
   </html>
```

I tried also with a dialog:

```
  <h:form>
     <p:dialog width="300px" height="400px" position="center bottom" 
dynamic="true" id="dialog" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">
        ${pageController.doc}
</p:dialog>

     <p:commandButton id="showDialog" update=":dialog" value="Display dialog"
        onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />
```

and the dialog contains the text, not the rendered content.

I tried with javascript also:

```
function renderAndShow(){
        var doc = "#{pageController.doc}";
        document.getElementById("dialog").innerHTML = doc;
        PF('dlg1').show();
    }
```

it displays the text, not the rendered page...

I couldn't find any ideas on the internet. Your help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: why do you store page as string? it is completely wrong.

Comment: How should I store/send it to the controller? I'm using a string buffer for creating the page. I can't change the creation of the file.  I just want to know what to do with the content of the page... Thanks

Comment: Please carefully read JSF wiki page http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Comment: The page I am generating in the BL it's supposed to be a statical page. It has nothing to do with the Web page I use to retrieve that file. It's a html page you could open statically with a browser...

Comment: then put it to your file system as static html.

Comment: How are you exactly doing that? The services go in the controller layer, but you're obtaining html content from the controller? That's a job for the view layer, where JSF servlet lies. Please consider refactoring your application according to MVC rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the characters in the static page I wanted to display was ecaped. I fixed it with:

```
<p:dialog id="dialog" width="1024px" height="500px" position="center center" 
dynamic="true" header="Basic Dialog" widgetVar="dlg1">
      <h:outputText escape="false" rendered="true" id="contid" value="#{pageController.doc}" />
</p:dialog>
```

So the escape false was doing all the magic. pressing the button:

```
<p:commandButton id="showDialog" update="contid" value="Open dialog"
        onclick="PF('dlg1').show();" type="button" />
```

displays the rendered page, without any trouble. No need to save the page in an html file and redirect to it.